# On Creating Recyclerview on below the child of ExpandableListview its position is messed up

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-adapter

Hey guys help me after searching for so much time at last i'm posting this I've created expandableListView which works fine but i want to create it Three level so I try a method where **I defined recyclerview in child view of expandable like this gonna set recyclerview visibility gone or visible** previously tried on recycler works fine but not in this **or guys tell me the best way to create 3 level expandablelistview or recycler for navigation with first two is static and last dynamic by value of first two**-:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/alarm_clock_24dp"
    android:id="@+id/child_icon"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/childItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:hint="gfchgc"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/child_icon"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drp_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/chevron_right_black_24dp" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/drp_icon"
    android:id="@+id/rec_childsubcat"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but on fetching value my recycler show data on second position child
[image: its mobile field data and showing on mobile accessories]

[image: and its mobile accessories data showing on laptop accessories]

here's is my adapter-:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
AppCompatActivity activity;
private ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList;

private String API = "***";
//chidsub category items defined

public static List<ChildSubCatModel> childSubCatModelList;
private ChildSubCatAdapter childSubCatAdapter;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.deptList = deptList;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition).getProductList();
    return productList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return super.getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    /*final int tempgroupPos = groupPosition;
    final int tempchildPos = childPosition;
    final ChildInfo detailInfo = (ChildInfo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    View row = view;
    if (row == null)
    {LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, parent, false);

        TextView tvb = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.childItem);
        RecyclerView mRecyclerChildSubCat = (RecyclerView) row.findViewById(R.id.rec_childsubcat);

        ChildViewHolder cholder = new ChildViewHolder();

        cholder.addView(tvb);
        cholder.addView(mRecyclerChildSubCat);


        row.setTag(cholder);
    }

    ChildViewHolder cholder = (ChildViewHolder) row.getTag();
    TextView tvb = (TextView) cholder.getView(R.id.childItem);
    RecyclerView mRecyclerChildSubCat = (RecyclerView) cholder.getView(R.id.rec_childsubcat);
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    // mRecyclerChildSubCat.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, 1, true));
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    childSubCatModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    childSubCatAdapter = new ChildSubCatAdapter(context, childSubCatModelList);
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setAdapter(childSubCatAdapter);
    *//*tvb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fetchNavigation(detailInfo.getHeadername(),detailInfo.getId());
            Toast.makeText(context,childPosition+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*//*
    tvb.setText(detailInfo.getName());*/

   // return row;
    final ChildInfo detailInfo = (ChildInfo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, null);

    }
    RecyclerView mRecyclerChildSubCat = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rec_childsubcat);
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    // mRecyclerChildSubCat.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, 1, true));
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    childSubCatModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    childSubCatAdapter = new ChildSubCatAdapter(context, childSubCatModelList);
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setAdapter(childSubCatAdapter);
    TextView childItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.childItem);
    childItem.setText(detailInfo.getName().trim());
    ImageView iv_childicon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.child_icon);
    iv_childicon.setImageResource(detailInfo.getDrawable());
    //title.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getVenue_item_name());
   childItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fetchNavigation(detailInfo.getHeadername(),detailInfo.getId());
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

    ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition).getProductList();
    return productList.size();

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return deptList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return deptList.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
                         ViewGroup parent) {

    GroupInfo headerInfo = (GroupInfo) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_items, null);
    }

    TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
    heading.setText(headerInfo.getName().trim());
    ImageView headerIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_icon);
    headerIcon.setImageResource(headerInfo.getDrawable());
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.expand_icon);
    if(isLastChild){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.expand_more_black_24dp);
    }else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.chevron_right_black_24dp);
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
public void fetchNavigation(final String headerName, final String categoryid) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, API,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                         childSubCatModelList.clear();
                        Log.d("TEST", "onResponse: " + response);
                        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String error = jsonRootObject.getString("error");

                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("navs");
                        if (error.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String category = jsonObject.optString("category");
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),category,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                if (category.equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
                                    JSONObject jsonnew = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    JSONArray jsonarrayROW = jsonnew.getJSONArray("child");
                                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonarrayROW.length(); j++) {
                                        JSONObject jsonObjectRow = jsonarrayROW.getJSONObject(j);
                                        String category_id = jsonObjectRow.optString("category_id");
                                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),category_id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        if (category_id.equalsIgnoreCase(categoryid)) {
                                            JSONObject jsonnew1 = jsonarrayROW.getJSONObject(j);
                                            JSONArray jsonarrayChild = jsonnew1.getJSONArray("child");
                                            for (int k = 0; k < jsonarrayChild.length(); k++) {
                                                JSONObject jsonObjectRow1 = jsonarrayChild.getJSONObject(k);
                                                String category_id1 = jsonObjectRow1.optString("category_id");
                                                String category_name = jsonObjectRow1.optString("category");
                                                childSubCatModelList.add(new ChildSubCatModel(category_name,category_id));
                                                //Toast.makeText(context,category_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        childSubCatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error");

                }
            }
    );
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
   /* static class ChildViewHolder {
    private HashMap<Integer, View> storedViews = new HashMap<Integer, View>();


    public ChildViewHolder addView(View view)
    {
        int id = view.getId();
        storedViews.put(id, view);
        return this;
    }

    public View getView(int id)
    {
        return storedViews.get(id);
    }
}*/
}
```

**after wrap content recyclerview only one recyclershows which was linked to laptop accessories and values update on it but its declared in adapter so it should show below every child** 
[image: After wrap_content recycler]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer i didn't define recycler in systematic way does some change and got it working..created **2 level expandable to 3 level**
its my latest listitem xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_resource"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_forward"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/fiber_manual_record_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_resources"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:hint=" Here is Resources heading. "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rec_reschild"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_resource"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And changed adapter String request to view holder instead of calling in an method:
like this-:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
AppCompatActivity activity;
private ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList;

private String API = "your Api";
//chidsub category items defined


public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.deptList = deptList;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition).getProductList();
    return productList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return super.getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    /*final int tempgroupPos = groupPosition;
    final int tempchildPos = childPosition;
    final ChildInfo detailInfo = (ChildInfo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    View row = view;
    if (row == null)
    {LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, parent, false);

        TextView tvb = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.childItem);
        RecyclerView mRecyclerChildSubCat = (RecyclerView) row.findViewById(R.id.rec_childsubcat);

        ChildViewHolder cholder = new ChildViewHolder();

        cholder.addView(tvb);
        cholder.addView(mRecyclerChildSubCat);


        row.setTag(cholder);
    }

    ChildViewHolder cholder = (ChildViewHolder) row.getTag();
    TextView tvb = (TextView) cholder.getView(R.id.childItem);
    RecyclerView mRecyclerChildSubCat = (RecyclerView) cholder.getView(R.id.rec_childsubcat);
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    // mRecyclerChildSubCat.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, 1, true));
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    childSubCatModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    childSubCatAdapter = new ChildSubCatAdapter(context, childSubCatModelList);
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setAdapter(childSubCatAdapter);
    *//*tvb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fetchNavigation(detailInfo.getHeadername(),detailInfo.getId());
            Toast.makeText(context,childPosition+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*//*
    tvb.setText(detailInfo.getName());*/

   // return row;
    final ChildInfo detailInfo = (ChildInfo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    final List<ChildSubCatModel> childSubCatModelList;
    final ChildSubCatAdapter childSubCatAdapter;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_resources, null);

    }
    final RecyclerView mRecyclerChildSubCat = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rec_reschild);
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    // mRecyclerChildSubCat.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, 1, true));
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    childSubCatModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    childSubCatAdapter = new ChildSubCatAdapter(context, childSubCatModelList);
    mRecyclerChildSubCat.setAdapter(childSubCatAdapter);
    TextView childItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_resources);
    childItem.setText(detailInfo.getName().trim());
    //ImageView iv_childicon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.child_icon);
   // iv_childicon.setImageResource(detailInfo.getDrawable());
    //title.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getVenue_item_name());
   childItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, API,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            mRecyclerChildSubCat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            try {
                                childSubCatModelList.clear();
                                Log.d("TEST", "onResponse: " + response);
                                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                String error = jsonRootObject.getString("error");

                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("navs");
                                if (error.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String category = jsonObject.optString("category");
                                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),category,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        if (category.equalsIgnoreCase(detailInfo.getHeadername())) {
                                            JSONObject jsonnew = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                            JSONArray jsonarrayROW = jsonnew.getJSONArray("child");
                                            for (int j = 0; j < jsonarrayROW.length(); j++) {
                                                JSONObject jsonObjectRow = jsonarrayROW.getJSONObject(j);
                                                String category_id = jsonObjectRow.optString("category_id");
                                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),category_id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                if (category_id.equalsIgnoreCase(detailInfo.getId())) {
                                                    JSONObject jsonnew1 = jsonarrayROW.getJSONObject(j);
                                                    JSONArray jsonarrayChild = jsonnew1.getJSONArray("child");
                                                    for (int k = 0; k < jsonarrayChild.length(); k++) {
                                                        JSONObject jsonObjectRow1 = jsonarrayChild.getJSONObject(k);
                                                        String category_id1 = jsonObjectRow1.optString("category_id");
                                                        String category_name = jsonObjectRow1.optString("category");
                                                        childSubCatModelList.add(new ChildSubCatModel(category_name,category_id));
                                                        //Toast.makeText(context,category_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                                childSubCatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("Volley", "Error");

                        }
                    }
            );
            RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

    ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition).getProductList();
    return productList.size();

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return deptList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return deptList.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
                         ViewGroup parent) {

    GroupInfo headerInfo = (GroupInfo) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_items, null);
    }

    TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
    heading.setText(headerInfo.getName().trim());
    ImageView headerIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_icon);
    headerIcon.setImageResource(headerInfo.getDrawable());
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.expand_icon);
    if(isLastChild){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.expand_more_black_24dp);
    }else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.chevron_right_black_24dp);
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
public void fetchNavigation(final String headerName, final String categoryid) {

}
   /* static class ChildViewHolder {
    private HashMap<Integer, View> storedViews = new HashMap<Integer, View>();


    public ChildViewHolder addView(View view)
    {
        int id = view.getId();
        storedViews.put(id, view);
        return this;
    }

    public View getView(int id)
    {
        return storedViews.get(id);
    }
}*/
}
```

got the output i need-:

[image: Got the output created 3 level expandable]